# one image in jquery slider not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I got a jquery template with 3 slides and i changed one of the image template to an image of same size, it works perfectly on chrome but not on IE.
here is the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code
`

```
   <section id="intro">
   <div id="slides">
   <div class="slides_container">
   <img src="images/banner1.png" width="960" height="300" alt="baner">
   <img src="images/translate.jpg" width="960" height="300" alt="baner">
   <img src="images/banner1.png" width="960" height="300" alt="baner">

   </div>
   </div>

   </section>
   <!--end intro-->`
```

Appreciate ur help

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: can you give a link to your live page?  Also, describe exactly what happens in ie, and mention any error in the console

Answer (score -1):

your error could be you have a duplicate file name there in your source

```
images/banner1.png
```

also, add

```
<!doctype html>
```

to the top of your html file

Comment: did that with same results

Comment: The point is the other image that came with the template is working in IE, the pic i edited which is customimage.jpg is the problem, i don't know why

Comment: The duplicate is working fine, it just repeats the image 2 times in the slider. also <!doctype html>  is added